# Change "administrator" account in Android

Tags: 7.0-nougat, multi-user

I am using Android 7.0 and I have multiple accounts and by default, the administrator of the device is the first user. Now, some of the privileges are reserved for the first user, like creating a hotspot and others.

I want to do that from the second user account as well, is it possible? How can I change the administrator on my Android device?

Answer (score 2):

The owner of the device remains the administrator no matter what. The device owner is set during the setup wizard, and cannot be changed without a reset.